# Why do I get different colours in scratched holograms?

Tags: optics, visible-light, diffraction, interference, hologram

[image: if we zoom this image we will see different colours in it]

I was making a scratched holograms and in result got different colours instead of white hologram

Comment: More of a [diffraction grating](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffraction_grating) than a hologram, maybe?

Comment: anyway whats the reason of this colours?

Comment: [Diffraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffraction). Light passing through a series of regularly spaced obstacles will interfere with itself and form a series of maxima (where the waves add up). Different wavelengths form maxima at different locations, so when white light passes through the grating, the different colours separate (they interfere constructively in different places). The wikipedia articles I linked to would be a good place to start.